# Tests are not executed in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: unit-testing, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

in my Play project I have some junit tests. Earlier this week I've been able to run the test from within play console using

```
test
```

command. I could see the successes and failures.

Unfortunately when I'd tried to run the tests today I've got:

```
[info] No tests to run for test:test
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 19, 2012 5:00:00 PM
```

message.

The tests are in the test folder of my project. What might be the problem?

Comment: It's probably not compiling your tests. Can you post a more verbose log output?

Comment: Sure, if only you could tell me where to look for the output?

Comment: I've also hit this recently, in my case the tests are compiled and even a test report is generated but none of the tests are actually executed. Weird part is that the test cycle stops for about 20 seconds to do seemingly nothing.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour too. It's incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Are your tests in the root of the test folder?
They won't work if they are in test/test/sometest.scala as far as I know.

Comment: If they are in a sub folder you need to do something like this: test-only packagename.testname